# How to secure custom parts of Identity Server

Tags: owin, identityserver3

I want to extend IdentityServer 3 with a 'admin' part where users can manage things like users, clients, etc. This part should be secured by the same ID server implementation (same app in IIS). Do I have to build a separate app or can I extend the same ID server solution? How do I configure the OWIN start up then? When  I have

```
app.Map("/Identity"....)
```

how do I add:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication
```

This results in an 'external' login provider, but that is not what I want. I also tried to add:

```
app.Map("/admin", config => config.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentiaction())
```

But that does not work as well, so:
How to have ID server and a client combined in one Solution?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [IdentityManager](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager) provided by developers of IdentityServer. This will get you up & running very quickly.

[Security Model](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/wiki/Architecture)

*The security model can be configured to only allow users running on the same machine or can be configured to use any Katana based authentication middleware to authenticate users.*

[Hosting Options](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/wiki/Installing-and-Hosting#hosting-identitymanager)

*IdentityManager is hosted as OWIN middleware. It can be configured with the UseIdentityManager extension method for Katana*

This is how you ["Get started"](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/wiki#getting-started)